# how can i get ussd measage string value?

Tags: android, ussd

i found this api [here](https://github.com/romellfudi/VoIpUSSD) to do my job but i didint know how to apply it to my application

i know there is description but how can i apply the api to onclick method to run the ussd and get the measage to string value then deside whatever i like based on the measage. can anyone help me with step by step application?
i have tried like this
in appcompatActivity i declared

```
 private HashMap map=new HashMap<>();
    private USSDApi ussdApi;
```

in oncreate method

```
USSDController.verifyAccesibilityAccess(this);
     USSDController.verifyOverLay(this);

    map.put("KEY_LOGIN",new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("koyu","waiting","loading","tinish yitebku")));
    map.put("KEY_ERROR",new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("chigir tefetrwal","problem","error","chigir")));
    ussdApi = USSDController.getInstance(this);
```

then in onclick method

```
atidabira.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            String suffix = Uri.encode("#");
            String ussd = "*" + "804"+suffix;



            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd));
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String[] PERMISSIONS={Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE};
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext,PERMISSIONS,REQUEST);
            }
            else {
                startActivity(intent);
            }


            ussdApi.callUSSDInvoke(ussd, map, new USSDController.CallbackInvoke() {
                @Override
                public void responseInvoke(String message) {


                    Toast.makeText(mContext, ""+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

                @Override
                public void over(String message) {

                }
            });



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to create a ussd Response Callback that will listen to response and use it on a Telephony.sendUssdRequest that takes three parameter (code eg *101#, the callback, and a Handler) method like this:

```
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }else{
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager=  (TelephonyManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        TelephonyManager telephonyManagerBySlot=telephonyManager.createForSubscriptionId(slot);

        TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback callback = new TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveUssdResponse(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, CharSequence response) {
                super.onReceiveUssdResponse(telephonyManager, request, response);
                Log.e("ussd",response.toString());
                Toast.makeText(activity, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(TelephonyManager telephonyManager, String request, int failureCode) {
                super.onReceiveUssdResponseFailed(telephonyManager, request, failureCode);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Rung USSD code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.e("ussd","failed with code " + Integer.toString(failureCode));
            }
        };

        try {
            Log.e("ussd","trying to send ussd request");
            telephonyManagerBySlot.sendUssdRequest(ussdCode,
                    callback,
                    handler);
        }catch (Exception e){

            String msg= e.getMessage();
            Log.e("DEBUG",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```